# Why are there sometimes app icon on the iPhone lockscreen?

Tags: iphone

Sometimes an icon is shown in the left bottom corner of the lock screen. Sometimes I can see some logic in it - when I plug the earphones, then the streaming radio app icon appers. I cannot start the app tapping the icon though. But sometimes an icon is just there without any visible connection to my actions, for example the Stack Exchange app icon:

[image: Stack Exchange icon on the lockscreen]

Why is that? What is it useful for and what can I do with them? If I tap them nothing happens.

Comment: Swiping up from the icon should do the trick.

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh yeah, that works.